# PowerPoint VBA to Update Embedded Spreadsheets

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint with 21 embedded spreadsheets that are used to populate charts in the PowerPoint. Each week data from two spreadsheets is copied into the embedded spreadsheets to update the charts with new data. I've started working on a macro to automate this process. I have the macro to open the spreadsheets with the new data, copy the data, then open the first embedded file. I am getting a run-time error'438' Object doesn't support this property or method on the paste function.

Note: I know linked spreadsheets would be desirable, but my customer wants the embedded excel files.

```
Sub UpdatedEmbeddedSpreadsheets()

Dim oData As ChartData
Dim oCht As Chart
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkBook As Object

'Open Weekly File
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\abc.xlsx", True, False)
xlWorkBook.sheets("Weekly ABC Chart").Range("B2:B5").Copy

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWorkBook = Nothing

'Open Embedded Spreadsheet
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Select
Set oCht = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Chart

oCht.ChartData.Activate
Set oData = oCht.ChartData
'The line below has the run-time error '438'
Debug.Print oData.Workbook.sheets("123").End(x1toright).Offset(0,-1).Paste

oData.Workbook.Close

Set oData = Nothing
Set oCht = Nothing

End Sub
```

Second Attempt:

```
Sub UpdatedEmbeddedSpreadsheets()

Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlWorkBook As Object

'Open Weekly File
Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
Set xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\abc.xlsx", True, False)
xlWorkBook.sheets("Weekly AVA Chart").Range("B2:B5").Copy

Set xlApp = Nothing
Set xlWorkBook = Nothing

'Open Embedded Spreadsheet
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).Select
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Chart.ChartData.Activate
Dim ChartData As Object
Set ChartData = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
ChartData.Visible = True
ChartData.Workbook.sheets("123").End(xltoright).Offset(0, -1).Paste

ChartData.Workbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: `x1toright` should be `xlToRight`  (you have a "1" not an "l")

Comment: However if you're using late binding you'll need to define that constant value, since PPT VBA won't recognize it.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Your are correct that it should be xlToRight. After revising it still throws the error. I get the error even if the code is something simple, like changing the value of A1 to 1. What is late binding?

Comment: If you haven't added a reference to the Excel object library to your PPT VBA project, then you're using late binding.  Without that reference, PPT VBA knows nothing specifically about the Excel object model, including any constants like `xlToRight`  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation

Comment: I added my second attempt to the original post. I am still getting the error. =/